# Vagrant localdev configuration ssh command with a non-zero exit status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, virtualbox, vagrant

I am using vagrant to work on an open source software

every time I do vagrant up, this is what I get

```
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

chmod +x /tmp/vagrant-shell && /tmp/vagrant-shell
```

and this as well

```
stdin: is not a tty
```

I tried chmod +x /tmp/vagrant-shell but there isn't a tmp/vagrant-shell

Here is a very detailed message that i copied and pasted from my terminal

http://pastebin.com/WQPGFmHb

There is a wiki of catarse, it basically asked me to
install vagrant,
install virtualbox
gem install librarian-chef
librarian-chef install (all the cookbooks in the rails app) 
gem install vagrant-vbguest

then do vagrant up 
then do vagrant provision

open localhost:3000 from now on, do vagrant up and vagrant halt

I installed the correct version of ruby for this project and the gem. I use 'rvm use (rub version)' to change to ruby that I should use for this project.

Hope this is ok?

The first time I did vagrant up to configure the box, I stopped midway because I forgot to do the previous steps, I am not sure if this directly impact anything.

Thank you so much for your help !

Comment: When using Chef 'stdin: is not a tty' is not an error, it's just chef-solo making a conclusion.

Comment: Your description sounds OK in general, the error about vagrant-shell sounds like there is something wrong with the base box (VM template your instances are cloned from) - what URL did you specify when doing `vagrant add URL`?